# Get Serial of Phone (IMEI) leads to an Error: READ_PHONE_STATE required

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-permissions

In my Android app I need the IMEI of the device. I used this code to get the IMEI:

```
try {
    TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String IMEINumber=tm.getDeviceId();
    String subscriberID=tm.getDeviceId();           
} catch (Exception ex){
    Toast.makeText(this,ex.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

At runtime I get following error:

> Error "Requires READ_PHONE_STATE: Neither user 10047 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because reading IMEI needs this permission, You have to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

to your Manifest file. See: [Manifest-Permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms)

Comment: Thanks Meiko

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mahmoud_mt.myfirstapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: you solved the problem? great :) then you can mark an answer as correct or write the correct answer.

Comment: On Marshmallow (SDK >= 23), requesting that permission pops up a dialogue reading that the app is asking to **"Manage and control phone calls"** which is not correct. This is, as I understand, must be marked as a bug for Google's Android developers. Reading IMEI is not the same as  Manage and control phone calls. Any idea how to prevent that alarming message?